# Displacement filter algorithm in OpenCV and blending 2 images

Tags: java, image, opencv, transparent, blend

I am trying to implement displacement algorithm, same as is used in Gimp or photohop. Describtion of this algorithm can be found here: http://docs.gimp.org/en/plug-in-displace.html

Everything works fine, very similar to photoshop, but i have 1 problem :)
I cant manage to properly blend 2 images (oryginal and this image after displace), and in resultant image i have a lot of black pixels. for example:

[image: originalimage]

[image: depthmap]

[image: result]

This is the code:

```
Mat img = Highgui.imread(path);
img.convertTo(img, CvType.CV_32SC3);

Mat map = Highgui.imread(path);
map.convertTo(map, CvType.CV_32SC3);

Mat displacedImg;

int coefficient = 15;
int displacement, intensity;
int[] dataMap = new int[3];
int[] dataImg = new int[3];
int[] dataDisplacedImg = new int[3];


Mat temp = new Mat(img.size(), img.type());

    for (int i = 0; i < img.height(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < img.width(); j++) {
            map.get(i, j, dataMap);
            intensity = dataMap[0];

            displacement = (int) (((intensity - 127.5) / 127.5) *(coefficient));

            img.get(i, j, dataImg);
            if (j + displacement <= img.width() && j + displacement >= 0) {
                temp.put(i, j + displacement, dataImg);
            }
        }
    }

displacedImg = temp;
```

Do you guys have any idea what i can in this case do ?
i want to use pixels from oryginal image instead of these black pixels.
I was thinking about transparent images, but i didnt find any solution.

Can you help ?

Comment: can you do it the other way around? from your displacement, create an "inverse displacement" where the the destination pixel (after displacement) have entries that hold some displacement values which point to the other direction (all untouched entries should be 0). Then to compute the new image you just set each pixel to `p=image(pixelPos + inverse_displacement(pixelPos))` there you are sure that each pixel is set to some value.

Comment: or easier: initialize your `temp` image with `img.clone()`